# Is it possible to cut a larger opening in this window / serving hatch of this pool house?

Tags: windows, framing, structural, shed, detached-structure

I'm curious if it is possible to cut a taller opening in this pool house or if that would create structural issues supporting the roof

[image: pool house]

From the inside you can see I would remove the 3 stubby studs and the 2x4 below it, leaving the 2x4 above that sits under the 4x4s that hold the roof. I'd add longer 2x4s to the left and right.

[image: inside]

Longer view of it:

[image: inside2]

From the front you can see I would need to cut into the exterior trim but also a 2x8. That's my biggest concern. Does that act as a header to distribute the load or are the horizontal 4x4s already doing that? Could I add a 4x4 to the corner for additional support (like the far corners where the bar-top is)?

[image: outside]

Comment: You may be over thinking this, those mini blocks or cripples are not doing anything except creating a surface for the siding. The king stud in the center is carrying the load you can pull it all out and it will be fine.

Comment: I did notice a notch in the header if this is 2 boards nailed together with notches at separate locations to create the header you will probably be ok but if both boards are joined in the same place your king studs will Cary the load but I would tie them with another board 3-4 ‘ longer  to brace the header.

Comment: @EdBeal, there is a 2x8 or 2x10 sitting on end that the siding is attached to.  That is most likely acting as the main beam that is carrying the weight of the roof framing.

Comment: At the end view that 2x8 or 2x 10 would be right at the cut line  I would not cut that and defiantly double it if the notch is in a single 2x10 cantilever with out sistering would not meet code even as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you will need to properly support the structure above the new opening.

As you can see, there is a header in place now fashioned of two 2x4s with blocking.  This is not a particularly strong support but I doubt there is much to support beyond the roof itself.

Doing what you are proposing with the lines on the photo, however, leaves no room for anything but that one 2x4 which is probably not enough support.

You could probably get at least as much support as you have now with a couple of 2x4s and a plywood spacer between then.  You'd lose a bit of opening height from what you've drawn but it would be close.

Comment: Those 2x s are not the header the header is the beam above that a 2x on its side like that has no strength it is used for a nailer.

Answer (score 0):

I see a half lap joint in the beam ( *is it a beam ?* ) on left side of photos 2 and 3. The header *seems* to be supporting this joint.

If the beam was of sufficient size and spanned the full width and supported on proper posts at the ends then i think you could do whatever you wanted in the space below. ( ***I am not an engineer, i do not know what size beam would be sufficient  for the length of that span.*** )

If the existing beam is sufficient and there was a post under that half lap joint you could shift the opening ( *or have the whole space open* ) to allow for the  proper post under the half lap joint .

The  2"x 8" ( 2"x 10" ? ) on the face of the header seems to be sufficient to support the joint but your plan would require removing that header.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 2x8 you're seeing is acting as the entire header. The 2 2x4 on the flat with the little cripple studs above them aren't really supporting any weight, especially since there isn't a vertical cripple above the jack stud at the edge of the opening.

You may get away with it if you put a 2x8 *above* the opening.

- Sit the bottom edge of it on the top flat 2x4.
- Nail it into the rafter supports above.
- Replace the jack studs at the sides of the opening with full height studs to bear the weight of the new header.
- Extend it beyond the opening so it's sitting above the jack studs.